# What is the recommended symbol for Volumetric flow rate?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, notation

I'm currently working on a paper with a mathematician.  He always writes $\dot Q$ as well as $\dot V$ for volumetric flow rate and claims both are standard notations.  Till now I always used $Q$ (without the dot) and $\dot V$.  Without success I tried to find a reference that will suggest us one or the other.  To my surprise I was unable to find it in the [IUPAP recommendations](http://iupap.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/A4.pdf) also the *Handbook of Chemistry and Physics* doesn't include it.

The only reference towards $Q$ was in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volumetric_flow_rate) - but that is no acceptable guideline to solve our conflict.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1083/2451) meta post.

Comment: Just to be helpful -- might I suggest simply picking one, making sure you define it in the text and moving on? Surely there are bigger things to work on in the paper than this! (And it helps that either one would make sense, but either needs defined)

Answer (score 2):

**V** may represent true mass flow, or the flow of density, rather than simply the flow of volume.  **Q** may represent a flow of volume unadjusted for density.  [TSI toolmaking co.](http://www.tsi.com/uploadedFiles/_Site_Root/Products/Literature/Application_Notes/GenPurp-Standard_vs_Volumetric.pdf) uses **Q** as "standard flow rate", but they make an instrument that converts **Q** to "**V**olumetricFlow" by applying a density correction.  See the link for the formula.

Another example of this use of **V** is [First-Sensor engineering Co.](http://www.first-sensor.com/cms/upload/appnotes/AN_Massflow_E_11153.pdf), which uses the symbol **V** as a translation of volumetric flow at standard conditions to true mass flow.

However, these other sources use **Q** to represent volumetric flow, with no adjustment for density:

[University of Idaho lecture notes](http://www.webpages.uidaho.edu/asm430/secure/lessons/PDF/L1M4_FV.pdf) use **Q**.

[LMNO engineering consulting firm](http://www.lmnoeng.com/flowrate.php) uses **Q**.

[Flow Simulation Ltd.](http://www.calculator.org/property.aspx?name=volumetric%20flowrate), an engineering software consulting firm] uses **Q** in its online calculator.

[FishXing](http://www.fsl.orst.edu/geowater/FX3/help/FX3_Help.html#8_Hydraulic_Reference/Continuity_Equation.htm), apparently a website dedicated to creating pathways for fish past dams, etc., uses **Q**.

[The Engineering Toolbox](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/pump-fan-power-d_632.html), an online resource for engineers and other technical professionals, uses **Q**.

[The Honeywell Co.](http://sensing.honeywell.com/mass-flow-vs-volumetric-flow-and-unit-conversion-tn-008043-2-en-final-06nov12.pdf) uses **Q**.

[The University of Minnesota](http://www.vhlab.umn.edu/atlas/physiology-tutorial/blood-flow.shtml) online Atlas of Human Cardiac Anatomy uses **Q**.

It seems to me that **V** and **Q** may refer to mass flow and volume flow, respectively.  But V also shows up as volume in certain contexts, so there may be no authoritative definition of these two symbols.